# Individual product Shipping charge for Wholesale Customer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using "Webshopapps Matrix Rate" extension and set as "Weight vs. Destination" for Shipping Methods. And it's working fine.

Also i want to set different individual product Shipping charge for Wholesale Customer. Is this possible?

Is there any solution or extension?

Please help.

Comment: Your best bet here is dropping WebShop Apps a line. One of their other modules will handle this, it's Product Matrix off the top of my head but they will advise you properly http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/shipping/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html

Comment: Hi McNab,

Thank for reply,

No, I want at the time of adding new product it give a option customer group (where we select Wholesale) and set the Shipping charge for this product.

I mean, it is the relation between individual product, customer group and Shipping charge.

But there is no effect on my all other extension.